# Get title of UIBarButtonItem while UI testing

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, ui-testing

I have a UIBarButtonItem inside a Toolbar and I have assigned an accessibility label and a title to it:

[image]

When I am UI testing, I can catch the button with this query (or Xcode does it for me when I'm recording):

```
        app.toolbars.buttons["AreaCachingButton"].tap()
```

Then, I m trying to verify its title:

```
        XCTAssertEqual(app.toolbars.buttons["AreaCachingButton"].title, "Abort Downloading")
```

but I cannot because the title is empty, although I obviously see its title on my phone.

Any tips on how to solve/circumvent this?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you are verifying the title?

Comment: with this line:         app.toolbars.buttons["AreaCachingButton"].title

Comment: @ApostolosApostolidis did you find anything related to this? if yes then please let me know the solution for this. thank you